# Is there any way to make it a lot easier? Without target1, target2

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Is there any way to replace the target1, target2, target3 .... parameters in this discord.py command?

```
@client.command() 
async def dm(ctx, message:str,target1:discord.Member,target2:discord.Member = None,target3:discord.Member = None,target4:discord.Member = None ,target5:discord.Member = None,target6:discord.Member = None  ):
    print(f'the message:{message} \n target: {target1}')
    message = message.replace('-',' ')
        await target1.send(f'{ctx.message.author} sends the following message: \n {message}')
        await target2.send(f'{ctx.message.author} sends the following message: \n {message}')
        await target3.send(f'{ctx.message.author} sends the following message: \n {message}')
        await target4.send(f'{ctx.message.author} sends the following message: \n {message}')
        await target5.send(f'{ctx.message.author} sends the following message: \n {message}')
        await target6.send(f'{ctx.message.author} sends the following message: \n {message}')
```

Also, the first parameter(i mean the first "target") must be set, others can be None

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Your title is not very meaningful, consider changing it so it is related to your issue.

Answer (score 3):

You could just allow multiple targets and check to make sure there is at least one passed:

```
async def dm(ctx, message: str, *targets: discord.Member):
    if not targets:
        #Throw error saying there needs to be at least one target passed

    message = message.replace('-',' ')
    msg = f'{ctx.message.author} sends the following message: \n {message}'
    for target in targets:
        await target.send(msg)
```